# Problem in displaying the selected value from dropdown in mozilla(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a list of SelectListItem in C# to populate the items of a dropdown.
When I select another option, IE8 just updates the same displaying the selected value, but in Mozilla, the selected value is not displayed.
I am using MVC 2.0. The whole page is reloaded with the selected option of the changed one.
I am confirming by seeing the "view source".
What might be the problem with Mozilla?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not what tags are for.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html? Also disable Javascript just to make shure that no clientcode is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"])%>
```

or try to change control name..

Comment: I am doing the same as u suggested, but when i try to reload the page, the "selected" attribute of Dropdown doesn't work with Mozilla, while it works fine with IE8.

Comment: check this link , that solves my problem.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1327178/2652936.aspx